# Issues with Google Analytics on our testing site preventing us going live

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We are having issues with the simple implementation of GA between the Live and Testing sites.

Our live site does not have any Tag Manager code as it was implemented before Tag manager came into existence. We now wish to add access to Tag manger so the Test site does contain this code.

The redacted code from our live site is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
{i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function()
{ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)}
,i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-********-*', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

The redacted code in our Test site is:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-********-*"></script>
<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag()
{dataLayer.push(arguments);}

gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-********-*');</script>
     <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-*******');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
</head>
<body id="*************" class="**************">
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-*******"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Please note that I have had to add a considerable amount of white space to get this forum to display the code as code and that this white space is not on either the live or test site.

Aside from the fact that the Google Analytics JavaScript is not directly after the `<body>` tag I do not think that there is a problem with the new code. Unless we also need to have the code that is on the live site as well as the new JavaScript. The Application appears to state no, but some web pages appear to state that we need all 3 pieces of JavaScript.

This has lead to quite a bit of confusion.

I have a Raw view that just shows everything from the live site. Due to the problem I'll outline shortly I set up another 'Raw' view under a different name for the live site. I expected that the number of users etc. would be the same on Analytics live view but they are different! Usually varying by 1 or 2 users but sometimes by as many as 5. Given that the views are the same, the website is the same & the Google id is the same I am baffled as to why this would be.

The reason I did the above is that I naturally want to filter out any test hits from our live data. I thus added an exclude filter on the live Analytics to exclude any hits from the Test site's IP address.

I then added a new view with an include filter matching the test sites IP address. This view should populate when I visit pages on the test site yet I get no hits at all.

If I remove the filter - so the new view is the same as my Raw view on the Live site I get the discrepancies I have describe above.

I am at a loss as to how to proceed.

Can someone look at the code I have posted and see if there are any errors?

Do we need all 3 JavaScript segments or are the 2 we have on the Test site sufficient?

Can someone suggest why two Raw views are producing different results?

Can someone suggest why adding the filter for the test site IP address results in 0 hits? I have confirmed that IP address is correct with our web provider.

Comment: There is really no need to use both GTM and gtag.js (the latter being the new "global" tag to deploy Google Analytics and advertising products). You would probably have less trouble if you integrated analytics via GTM.

Comment: Thank you Eike, Can I just confirm - as I am not that familiar with GA - that we only need the code we have on our test site and not the code on our live one? If so any idea why my filter is not working and why when I remove the filter I get different results for the two, apparently identical, raw views?